# Filter files that do not contain 3 strings

Tags: powershell

```
gci -r | Where-Object {
    !($_ | Select-String "BGM+795" -Quiet) -and
    !($_ | Select-String "BGM+227" -Quiet) -and
    !($_ | Select-String "BGM+781" -Quiet)
}
```

This is what i have now. All files are appearing.

Using just one of those "filters" works just fine, but I want to be able to filter on multiple at the same time.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you want the files that don' t contain *all* of the given strings or files that don't contain *any* of the given strings?

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` supports a `-Exclude` parameter (which is a string array). 
Therefore you could write:

```
gci -r | Where-Object { $_ | sls -Exclude "BGM+795", "BGM+227", "BGM+781"}
```

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_ | Select-String -Pattern "(BGM\+227|BGM\+781|BGM\+795)") }
```

This did the trick.

Andreas' answer failed on me: SLS is not a known cmdlet.